# It is possible to use Attributes to remember old value of a variable?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

Like my question above I would like know it.

Want I want to do is to make my life easier if I am working with values where I need to check changes. And if there is many many variables so I have to make always duplicated variables like:

```
health = 100;
oldHealth = health; // this should be in the attribute class for example
```

this makes me crazy. So I tried to make attributes but I don't know really how I would know when a variables is changed.. I guess I need to loop all the time myself or it is there any events? Also need to read the current value before it would get changed.

Comment: Attributes are not meant to know about the item they decorate, they add information to the member but they don't know about it. Via reflection you can get the attribute to know what it deals with but its first purpose is to give extra information on the manifest of the class.

Comment: [Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653979.aspx) are for another purpose. Do not use them in this case

Comment: It doesn't need to be attribute. Was just an idea. My alternate way were to make a class with all types which just current value and the old value.

Answer (score 3):

when you only need to know if there is a change and in the case you need the "old" value. Just use the standard property implementation:

```
int _health;
int Health 
{
    get {return _health;
}
set {
    // check your "old" value here and do some stuff
    _health = value; // than asign the new value thats inside the keyword "value"
}
```

Comment: No not only. But the problem there is I would still need here two different variables. Imagine its a network stuff and I don't want to send every frame everything if the value is same like before.. id, health, mana, shield, armor, velocity, position, rotation and bla... I would need for all a second variable. I need to check later like if ( Health != Health.oldvalue) something like that. But this brings me to new idea. I could maybe call in the set call a function. so I could avoid changes conditions on the loop. But still I had little bit same like before. I would do this on all variables :S

Comment: with this approach you dont have 2 variables its 1 var and 1 property (method) and when you change the value you can just put some methodcall in the "set" part that indicates that some variable has been changed and needs to be sind to the client. otherwise look at the "inotifypropertychanged" implementation. you could build your own version of it.

but maybe it is better to send every tick alle of the mandantory data to prevent that the client will get stale within the ticks. but this depends on your solution :)

Comment: if it was the answer to your question please mark it